# Downsampling for beginners using QGIS

Tags: qgis, gdalwarp

I apologise from the outset. I need a full run through of working gdalwarp to downsample a raster to match another i.e. [How to resample GeoTIFF images to the same resolution?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/73046/how-to-resample-geotiff-images-to-the-same-resolution). Using QGIS 2.12.

Using '-tr switch' what command goes in next so I specify the resolution to switch too.

Or how do I find the resolution from each raster to ascertain the height and width values necessary?

Comment: You can find resolutions with gdalinfo. Gdalwarp options are listed in http://www.gdal.org/gdalwarp.html and usage is simply `gdalwarp ... -tr 10 10 ... input.tif output.tif`for creating 10 m pixels. I suggest to use -tap option as well.

Comment: that seems like it would work. However still struggling to ascertain the rasters resolution. The pixel size is displayed as 0.00208333. i'm assuming 1.0 isn't 1m.

Comment: Pixel size is using the same units than the coordinate system. With the value you have I guess your data is in EPSG:4326 and the unit is then degrees. It may not be an optimal projection for you.