# Change pixel size of 30m for 23.5m in QGIS

Tags: qgis, resampling, file-size, pixel

I need to change pixel size in raster file file with Pixel Size = (28.086057277202915,-28.086057277202915) using Qgis for Pixel Size = (23.951601289061028,-23.952379920305706) what kind of function I can use?

Comment: [Related post](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/73046/how-to-resample-geotiff-images-to-the-same-resolution). You can use GDAL's Warp function to do the job.