# Change a raster resolution and size according another raster in QGIS

Tags: qgis, raster, resolution, pixel

I have downloaded two rasters set from SoilGrids (like pH, carbon stock... with 250m resolution) and WorldClim (climatic biovariables with 30s resolution). I want to use them in RStudio for Species Distribution Modelling (SDM)  and I want to make them equal in terms of resolution and extent (to avoid later problems using raster with R). I need to work with global scale rasters with 30s resolution. It would be great that the modified units or modified pixels are the average of the originals that they come from.

I used Raster calculator with a soil pH layer but it doesn't fit as I expect. Then I used a Raster masking using WorldClim biovariables as mold. It doesn't work either. So, what I really want is to make this pack of raster with the same position and size to use them as variables of my SDM.

I'm pretty noob at this. I have just worked with QGis for nearly a month and I don't have clear many concepts so I ask you for patience.

Comment: Dear Javier, welcome to gis.stackexchange community. In your question, it would be nice to explain acronyms so that your question is more clear (e.g.  SDM stands for Species Distribution Modelling). The concept you are interested in is called resampling. This question can be useful: https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/73046/resampling-geotiff-images-to-same-resolution-using-qgis

Comment: Hi, Ilias. Thank you for the edit and the advices. Sorry for my english. I tried what it's posted and it wasn't successful. I don't what to doy to use the 2 set of maps in RStudio.